# Is there a curvesAtBottom equivalent in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchos

On watchOS you have the curvesAtBottom and curvesAtTop
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacetable/3042495-curvesatbottom
It allow to have rescale on elements on top and bottom of a view on a WKInterfaceTable [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAlIE.png)

I can't find an equivalent on SwiftUI

Comment: Are you attempting to replicate this in SwiftUI on an iPhone or Mac?

Comment: @xTwisteDx on AppleWatch

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `curvesAtBottom` is a feature in SwiftUI for watchOS 5.1+ only. The closest I think you'll get without building your own component, is `PickerStyle.wheel`.

example:

```
enum Flavor: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case chocolate, vanilla, strawberry
    var id: Self { self }
}

struct MyTestView1: View {
    @State private var selectedFlavor: Flavor = .chocolate

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Picker("Flavor", selection: $selectedFlavor) {
                Text("Chocolate").tag(Flavor.chocolate)
                Text("Vanilla").tag(Flavor.vanilla)
                Text("Strawberry").tag(Flavor.strawberry)
            }
        }.pickerStyle(.wheel)
    }
}
```

[PickerStyle Wheel example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMloo.png)

Comment: Unfortunately its not a swiftUI feature but a swiftLang feature which work with WkTableView. Moreover swift lang is not recommanded on watchOS since Xcode 14